# function not executed within custom function in R

Tags: r, function

When using `spplot {sp}` in R, everything works fine. However, when I use it within a function, `spplot` seems to do nothing whenever anything follows up.

Here is an example of what I intend to do:

A) this works:

```
#load packages
require(gplots)
require(sp)
require(profvis)

#create spatial polygon with categories-attribute
grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(10,10))
polys <- as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grd)

myAttribute <- c(rep("A",12), rep("B",59), rep("C",29))
df <- data.frame(myAttribute=myAttribute, row.names=row.names(polys))
polygons(df) <- polys

#plot polygons by attribute
spplot(df["myAttribute"], col.regions=c("green","yellow","blue"),oma=c(4,4,4,4))
```

[image]
B) this also works:

```
test <- function (){
textplot("text to appear", halign="right", mar=c(4,4,4,4), col="black")
pause(1)
spplot(df["myAttribute"], col.regions=c("green","yellow","blue"),oma=c(4,4,4,4))
}
test()
```

[image]

C) however, when anything follows after `spplot` within the function, `spplot` is skipped. The plot should appear for 5 seconds before the next plot is drwan. However, the plot is not drawn at all.

```
test <- function (){
textplot("text to appear", halign="right", mar=c(4,4,4,4), col="black")
pause(1)
spplot(df["myAttribute"], col.regions=c("green","yellow","blue"),oma=c(4,4,4,4))
pause(5)
plot(df)
}
test()
```

[image]

Is this a known problem of `spplot`? Are there any fixes to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, my final solution was simply to use `print()` in the custom function:

```
test <- function (){
textplot("text to appear", halign="right", mar=c(4,4,4,4), col="black")
pause(1)
 print(spplot(df["myAttribute"], col.regions=c("green","yellow","blue"),oma=c(4,4,4,4)))
pause(5)
plot(df)
}
test()
```

This approach first printed
[image]

and - as inteded - after 5 seconds
[image]